# How do I export data in Windows CMD terminal to a csv file?

Tags: windows, csv, cmd, export-to-csv

I'm using Windows10, and I would like to export data in windows cmd terminal in a csv file using windows command.

Please advise how can I save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just redirect the output to a file, with any extension:

**Windows and Linux Syntax :**

`SomeCommand > SomeFile.csv`

Or if you want to append data:`SomeCommand >> SomeFile.csv`

**Linux Syntax:**

If you want stderr as well use this:`SomeCommand &> SomeFile.csv`

or this to append:`SomeCommand &>> SomeFile.csv`

if you want to have both stderr and output displayed on the console and in a file use this:

`SomeCommand 2>&1 | tee SomeFile.csv`

[Here is the info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: `&>` is not Windows syntax!

Comment: Windows equivalent to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR: `>file.csv 2>&1`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**NB:** 'n.e' is not existing but it doesnt mean it cant be done but just complicated
**List**:

**command > output.csv**

The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.

**command >> output.csv**

The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

**command 2> output.csv**

The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.

**command 2>> output.csv**

The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

**command &> output.csv**

Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.

**command &>> output.csv**

Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file..

**command | tee output.csv**

The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.

**command | tee -a output.csv**

The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

**(*)**

Bash has no shorthand syntax that allows piping only StdErr to a second command, which would be needed here in combination with tee again to complete the table. If you really need something like that, please look at "How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?" on Stack Overflow for some ways how this can be done e.g. by swapping streams or using process substitution.

**command |& tee output.csv**

Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.

**command |& tee -a output.csv**

Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.